# How to make mongoose data typesafe in typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

My model/order.ts:

```
import mongoose from './db'
import { ICard } from './cards'


export interface IOrder extends mongoose.Document {
    cardID: ICard['_id'];
    paid: boolean;
    name: string;
    street: string;
};

export const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cardID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    paid: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    street: { type: String, required: true },
})


const Order = mongoose.model<IOrder>('Order', OrderSchema);
export default Order;
```

**now in my controller/orderController.ts, where the orderData should be typechecked, but is not:**

```
import Order, { IOrder } from '../model/orders';
let orderData:IOrder =  new Order({
    cardID: 33,
    paid: "I don't care, I am not a boolean",
    name: 33333,
    city: "I am new, not defined in IOrder" //street missing here
});
```

What I tried is this, but it is a bit an overhead; I introduce "IOrderType" and wire them together:

```
import mongoose from './db'
 import { ICard } from './cards'

export interface IOrder extends mongoose.Document, IOrderType {
}; // wireup

export interface IOrderType { //new IOrderType
        cardID: String;
        paid: Boolean;
        name: String;
        street: String;
}

    export interface IOrder extends mongoose.Document {
        cardID: ICard['_id'];
        paid: boolean;
        name: string;
        street: string;
    };

    export const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        cardID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
        paid: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        street: { type: String, required: true },
    })


    const Order = mongoose.model<IOrder>('Order', OrderSchema);
    export default Order;
```

After this my data is validated... is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 2):

There's this library [typegoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typegoose) that can help with mongoose data typed. But I prefer to declare my own interface for the type like you did in solution you proposed